# Matrix subset includes NA

Tags: r, matrix, subset

This question is likely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24040758/1623354). I am not understanding why the vector returned when subsetting a matrix using `[` includes `NA` values.

```
set.seed(1234)
xmpl <- matrix(sample(c(1:4, NA_real_), 25, replace = TRUE), 5, 5)
# > xmpl
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    4    4   NA    2
# [2,]    4    1    3    2    2
# [3,]    4    2    2    2    1
# [4,]    4    4   NA    1    1
# [5,]   NA    3    2    2    2

# > xmpl[xmpl == 1]
# [1]  1 NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1
```

The replacement works like I expected:

```
xmpl[xmpl == 1] <- 10
# > xmpl
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   10    4    4   NA    2
# [2,]    4   10    3    2    2
# [3,]    4    2    2    2   10
# [4,]    4    4   NA   10   10
# [5,]   NA    3    2    2    2
```

Should I be using `%in%` rather than `==` when extracting a vector from a matrix? Why does the assignment/replacement behavior differ from the subsetting behavior -- ie. why would the NA values not be replaced by `10` when `xmpl[xmpl == 1] <- 10` call.

Comment: Going out on a limb here, the behavior is difference because extraction depends on `[` and extraction/replacement depends on `[<-`

Comment: Although some people would complain about the doubling of keystrokes, `%in%` can replace (and is better to use than) `==` in most situatons. `xmpl[xmpl %in% 1]; xmpl[xmpl %in% c(1, NA)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?"["`, **NAs in indexing**:

"When **extracting** [i.e. `[`], a numerical, logical or character **`NA` index** picks an unknown element and so **returns `NA`** in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result"

"When **replacing** [i.e. `[<-`] (that is using indexing on the lhs of an assignment) **`NA` does not select any element** to be replaced"

Comment: it should be `?'['`, (quotations needed for special characters).

Answer (score 1):

A `matrix` in R is just a vector which has a `dim` attribute (see `?matrix`).

```
dim(xmpl)
## [1] 5 5
attributes(xmpl)
##$dim
##[1] 5 5
```

Thus, if you do

```
dim(xmpl) <- NULL
```

`xmpl` will become a vector

```
xmpl
# [1]  1  4  4  4 NA  4  1  2  4  3  4  3  2 NA  2 NA  2  2  1  2  2  2  1  1  2
```

Now, if you''ll look at this vector carefully you will understand the result of

```
xmpl == 1
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## [20] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`==` just scans the whole vector and returns `TRUE` when encountering `1` and `NA` when encountering `NA`. `NA` in R is basically saying:

> "I don't know what this value is. It could be either `1` or any other
>   number, thus I won't exclude it, but neither say what it is"

So when you do

```
xmpl[xmpl == 1]
## [1]  1 NA  1 NA NA  1  1  1
```

R selects all the `TRUE` and `NA` values from `xmpl == 1` *in their appearance order* while ignoring all the `FALSE` values, i.e. you have one `TRUE`, then `NA`, then another `TRUE`, then another two `NA`s, etc.

For the `[<-` see @Henriks answer

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the behavior is expected since

```
xmpl[xmpl == 1]
```

will generate a TRUE/FALSE vector that will be used to select elements from the matrix. Now since the comparison NA == 1 cannot generate neither TRUE nor FALSE (it is NA per definition) the best choice is to return NA instead of postulating that it is either. Think of it like this: What is the value at the position NA of the matrix? Well since an NA position does not exist the only reasonable value to return is NA.

Now regarding assignment

```
xmpl[xmpl == 1] <- 10
```

again results in a vector with TRUE or FALSE and NA in this case. Now it's the INDEX that is NA and not the value NA that will be replaced. So how do you replace a value at POSITION NA? Well you can't since it would be nonsence. That's why only the TRUE cases gets replaced by 10.

Again this is what I would expect. So to answer your question: Yes in this case %in% would be more suitable.